# Yii2 get role of the logged in user

Tags: yii2

Can someone please explain to me how to use this function

```
getRoleByUser()
```

for related tables to get role of logged in user

I tried this

```
$Role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
    print_r($Role);
    exit();
```

but I got the following error

```
Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::findByUsername
```

Comment: Error seems to be unrelated to the code you posted - you probably have some error in your `WebUser` component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($user_id);
```

From the auth manager you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$userRole = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
```

like

```
if ($userRole) {

  foreach ($userRole as $role) {
     $roles[] = $role->name;
  }

  // if user have 1 role then $userRole will be a string containing it
  // othewhise let $userRole be an array containing them all

   $userRole = count($roles) === 1 ? $roles[0] : $roles ;
 }
```